# Is there anybody who knows how to make use of seedDMS on window10 wampserver?

Tags: windows, wampserver, document-management

SeedDMS is opensource document management system, i searched a lot but not found any simple way to utilise this seedDMS service on my window 10 system with wampserver.

I downloaded from this below link,
https://sourceforge.net/projects/seeddms/files/seeddms-5.1.10/

I followed this link to download and work as said but it not worked.
https://sourceforge.net/p/seeddms/discussion/general/thread/785416ca/

Please help if anybody ever had tried for this seedDMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the way to install in wampserver and windows 10. I will share a link of the video shortly.

follow the steps in video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Yg-E9rUC5o&list=PLLB0fpxTsli2rDw8GlrrkF9VqSmvXlYJi